# Adding AWS SES DKIM for domain using G Suite

Tags: g-suite, dkim, amazon-ses

My company has a domain `acme.com` with multiple subdomains running various AWS servers which are accessible via subdomains like `client1.acme.com` and we're also using G Suite for email.

I'd like to move any emails sent by various apps to AWS SES and also add DKIM DNS records from AWS SES.

If I add DKIM DNS records for the domain `acme.com`, does it affect the emails sent through G Suite as presumably GMail wouldn't add any of the DKIM verification?

Thanks